# Function that takes a char array as a parameter

Tags: c++

There is a function I want to use that takes `char str[]` as a parameter. I want to call the function giving a string input.

```
void someFunction (char str[]) {
    /* ... */
}

// Works.
someFunction("1010101");

// Does not work.
string someString;
someFunction(someString);
```

How can I get the second call to work?

**EDIT:** I cannot change the function's input parameters.

Comment: `someFunction(someString.c_str());`

Comment: @Cody: won't compile, `c_str()` is const.

Comment: I was leaving that part to the imagination, that's why it was only a comment. `someFunction` should probably be `const`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
someFunction(const_cast<char*>(someString.c_str()));
```

Although I'm not sure what will happen if `str` gets modified.

It's probably best if you just modify the original function to take a different parameter type.

Comment: Neither is the standard. That's why we call it "undefined behavior".

Comment: This seems to work. Anything wrong with using this? All my strings are stored in an array so I'm just reading them and they are not being changed.

Comment: @CodyGray I just wrote I'm not sure what will happen if they try and modify the string because I'm not sure what would, I assume it wouldn't be good, however.

Comment: @DomX23 if you're only reading them and not changing them, then they should be labelled as `const` (if not only for self documentation).  A non-`const` type can cast to a `const` of the same type, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the nature of the string manipulations. If you read but don't write the string, change the prototype to `const char str[]` and use `someString.c_str()`, like others are suggesting.

If you change the characters *but not the length* of the string, use `&*someString.begin()`.

If you extend/truncate the string, it's easier to pass a `string&` and work in terms of the string object. Less trouble, honestly.

Comment: Can you support this: "change the characters..., use &*someString.begin()"?  My concern is that a Standard library may expect strings to be immutable, or reference counted in some way, or internally have a checksum for some obscure purpose etc..  So, while you could almost certainly overwrite that memory without causing a SIGSEGV or similar, your changes could be reflected in other strings that would be expected to be unrelated, and/or invalidate some internal class invariants.  That said, if it's a newly created `string` that hasn't been copied, it's extremely likely to be safe....

Comment: Worked for me in the past :) Also, think of it this way. begin() returns an iterator which returns a writeable reference. There's no way to intercept you writing into that reference, so the reference has to point at the real storage behind the string, not at some temporary. Also, the standard requires that the string is stored as a contiguous memory block - so the rest of the characters are in the same block. QED.

Comment: sound point re `begin()` - the `string someString; someFunction(someString);` usage in the question would invoke the non-`const` version, and an implementation would have to go out of its way to screw up after that....

Answer (score 1):

What you want for `std::string` is `void someFunction(std::string& str);`

There's a reason for the issue -- a `std::string`'s data is not guaranteed to be contiguous memory (at least, before C++11). Therefore, manipulating its buffer as a contiguous allocation (`char[]`) is a very bad idea.

casting away the `const` of `std::string::c_str()` is also a bad idea. One immediate problem you may face is that a `std::string` implementation may share backing string allocations with other `std::string` instances (copy-on-write), and you will end up modifying the values of other `std::string`s. Of course, there are many other bad things that could go wrong in their own implementation-defined ways -- the standard left this very flexible for the implementors of standard libraries.

> EDIT: I cannot change the function's input parameters.

Use a `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your function take a `std::string` instead:

```
void someFunction (std::string &str) {
```

Comment: I get the following errors: .cpp:207: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
.cpp:207: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void someFunction(char*)

Comment: the first version may be dangerous if `someFunction` tries to modify the contents.

Comment: I can not change the function parameter.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev True, removed that. I wonder why `c_str` is const, even for a non-const `string`.